# PHP - Behat - Page Object Extension - Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function FeatureContext::__construct()

Tags: php, ui-automation, behat

Trying to implement the behat-page-object-extension and when running behat I get the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function FeatureContext::__construct()

Github for the project -> https://github.com/andrew0071/MyBehatProject

**composer.json**

[image]

**behat.yml**

[image]

**Homepage.php**

[image]

**FeatureContext.php**

Injecting page objects into a context file
Page objects will be injected directly into a context file if they’re defined as constructor arguments with a type hint:
[image]

**test.feature.php**

[image]

**When running the test**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your [behat.yml](https://github.com/andrew0071/MyBehatProject/blob/master/behat.yml) is all messed up. Indentation in YAML matters.